# Record using OPEN AL

Tags: openal

Im trying to record using open al, Ive searched around and have only found examples of people recording from the mic.

I want to record sounds that openal is playing.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: this is OS specific ... which OS ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an OpenAL question from what I see. I don't believe OpenAL has any ability to go from the buffered data back to .wav file. You would need to do something like in the below thread.

[Saving audio byte[] to a wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991391/saving-audio-byte-to-a-wav-file)